# Battery Usage for individual UWP Apps

Tags: wpf, uwp, battery

I have a WPF .NET application written in C#. I'm trying to obtain the battery usage for each individual UWP app programatically as shown in the image below.

[image]

I have looked at the [Windows.Devices.Power Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.power) however this only returns the overall battery status rather than per-process readings. I have also tried searching the registry for relevant keys but could not find anything.

Does anyone know whether this is even possible to do?

Comment: What's you are developing, UWP app or WPF application?

Comment: I am developing a WPF application.

Comment: Try looking at [this post on `AppDiagnosticInfo`](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/). There are some videos too